# Monitor css properties while JQuery animation is running

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm searching for a way to keep track of the css properties while a jquery animation is running.

For example:

I habe a div which will slide into the page. When the animation is done, everything looks fine but wihtin the animation the div is a few pixels to low and i'd like to see which css property  this is causing. But the animation is too fast to see anything in the debugger.

Is there a way to monitor css properties in one of the browsers debuggers while an animation is running?

Comment: why don't you animate it in a different way? let's say a step by step css property being changed every time you press a button. That way you could watch the behaviour of your div during the whole process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow down the animation so you can watch the numbers in your inspector.

```
.animate({left:"+=250"},20000)
```

Comment: Accepted since this is by far the easiest approach (and i'm a little emberassed that i didn't get this myself since i somehow included part of the answer in my question saying "the animation is too fast". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `step:` callback option for the jQuery animation.  It will send you the exact property that it is about to set right before it gets set and then you can do a console.log() on it to analyze what's going on.

See the [jQuery `animate()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more info on the step callback.

Comment: Also thanks for this answer it's pretty useful and it seems like the more appropriate way of monitoring css properties. But for a fast shot slowing down the animations seemed a bit easier to me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

have u tried using mozilla developer netwrks 'Monitoring DOM changes'?
check out this link..

[monitoring dom changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_School/Appendix_F%3a_Monitoring_DOM_changes)